# Vue3 component with 'is router link' ref returns a proxy instead of an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm kinda new with vue so I'm trying to use the good practices, but I have a quick question:

I'm using a `component` object with a ternary making it either a `section` or a `router-link`, and this `component` object has a `ref` I need to do some stuff with it.

In the case the `component` is a `section`, `ref` will return the object and I will be able to do my stuff, but in the case it's a `router-link` the `ref` returns a `Proxy`.

How can I get the same object that I get when it's `section` when I get `Proxy` returned?

EDIT:

Template:

```
<template>
    <component :is="(isLink)?'router-link':'section'" :to="(isLink != null)?link:''" ref="pop_target">
</template>
```

in `mounted`:

```
contentPop(this.$refs.pop_target, true) // First arg is an html object
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the ref from the composition API?

Comment: I have `<component is:="(condition)?'router-link':'section'" ref="myTarget">`, it will gives an object when it's `section` and a `Proxy` with the `router-link` args